Application search utilizing apache SOLR triggers stall error in a random pattern
Keep getting the SOLR stall error in a random pattern, Came across this forum for fields in spatial search had to be compressed before indexing...does that mean, solrconfig.xml change to make slave nodes to have internal or to make any field level compression in the Data import handler config having the Database query for delta and full import?
Any insight on "compression" before indexing?
Does this impact all Solr search even if documents are text/string/date fields, irrespective of size, Not any files or image?
